# Host a subdomain from an IIS7 server on another server

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-server, web-hosting

I am running a network with two server, one running SBS 2008 which hosts a majority of the network services (DNS, DHCP, Exchange, IIS, DC, AD...), including the primary webpage at mydomain.com. The other server is a linux box running an apache web server. I'm trying to set the apache server to host the site site2.mydomain.com. I have changed the DNS settings on the first server so that site2.mydomain.com can be accessed from the internal network, but I cannot access site2.mydomain.com from the internet. I have tried using server farms and application request routing cache, as described on this page, http://forums.iis.net/t/1156458.aspx, but I still can't access site2.mydomain.com from the internet.

I don't have much experience with web servers, I usually just administer local networks, so I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a firewall? Do you have almost two public ip addresses?

Comment: There is a firewall. All ports that need to be open are forwarded to the first server. We only have one IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one public ip address you must use a reverse proxy ([pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/), [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), etc).

Another solution maybe use a different port for second domain.